# How accessing ng-content value when it's text only?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access the value of a `span` which value is given by `ng-content`.

I've got a button component containing this html in the template:

```
<span #text class="o-button-label">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

so I can have

```
<my-button>Hello</my-button>
```

turning into

```
<span #text class="o-button-label">
    Hello
</span>
```

Now I want to get that text to be able to use it as well in an `aria-label`.
Among other things, I tried the following in `my-button` component:

```
@ViewChild('text') textElement: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('textElement', this.textElement.nativeElement.value);
}
```

But that always give me `undefined`. Replacing `value` by `nodeValue` returns `null`. I checked `this.textElement.nativeElement` which is the `span` as expected, the `span` contains its value as expected, but I can't find a way to get that text value.

All the search I did points to the use of `@ViewChild` as I did, but it's always to get some components or DOM nodes ([like in this good topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408912/how-do-i-access-ng-content)), not text only, so is it even possible to get text value injected by `ng-content`?

Comment: Why not binding its value to a Typescript variable? E.G.: On your HTML: `<span #text class="o-button-label">
        {{mytext}}
    </span>` and in your component: `mytext: string = 'Hello';`?  By the way, make sure that you explicitly implements AfterViewInit on your component, for example `export class MyAppComponent implements AfterViewInit`. Is it implemented in a explicit way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to change the value property to textContent

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('textElement', this.textElement.nativeElement.textContent);
}
```

Comment: I knew I was close! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Now it seems to be `innerText` -  this.textElement.nativeElement.innerText