# Angular - template reference on ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngcontent

I need to render dynamic content around an input in Angular app.

My idea was to create a custom component, and then use `ng-content` to bind the behavior to that input. Like so:

```
<my-wrapper>
    <input type="text" otherAttributes...>
</my-wrapper>
```

And my wrapper would be something like below.

HTML:

```
<span>
    <ng-content #myRef></ng-content>
    <button (click)="perform(myRef)">Click me!</button>
</span>
```

And .ts function:

```
perform(myRef: HTMLIntpuElement) {
    myRef.value = 'something else';
}
```

Now, I know that `ng-content` doesn't actually exist, and that I can't really place reference on it since that content can be more than one element, but is there a way to get to it the "Angular way", instead of using brute force i.e. native element?

Comment: you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408912/how-do-i-access-ng-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is solvable with @ContentChildren/@ContentChild.
They are similar with @ViewChildren/@ViewChild but @ContentChild looks into ng-content while @ViewChild not.

```
 <input type="text" #myRef>
```

and in typescript file:

```
 @ContentChildren('myRef') items: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```