# How to get children projected component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a template:

```
<app-adresat-list [parent]="block">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"> </ng-container>
</app-adresat-list>
```

Inside template `#children` can be rendered different components one of them is:

```
<app-adresat [block]="block"></app-adresat>
```

How to get list of all `app-adresat` components from `app-adresat-list`?

Comment: Normally you would use `@ContentChildren` to get the projected content of a component.
e.g. `@ContentChildren(AdresatComponent) contentChildren!: QueryList<AdresatComponent>;` for your case

Comment: Check this answer out :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408912/how-do-i-access-ng-content

Comment: Where to get it in ngOnit?, Does it find only closest child components ot all children?

Comment: What if I need to find last @ContentChildren component and clone it and add to the list of components?

Comment: I get zero children components `this.contentChildren.length` despite they are present